# Realm synchronous writes from intent service

Tags: java, android, realm

I'm using a Realm database from and Intent service and UI, since it is part of a library I can't call or set the default of the Realm, so I retrieve the realm using Realm.getInstance(config) for EVERY intent, and because I can't reuse the realm not knowing what thread I'll be running on I also cannot use asynchronous writes.

As such I am getting the following error each time I write a record

"Mixing asynchronous queries with local writes should be avoided. Realm will convert any async queries to synchronous in order to remain consistent. Use asynchronous writes instead."

I'm assuming by "local writes" the author means "synchronous"?

From my understanding of realm utilization in this scenario I don't believe there is any alternative?

Am I correct in understanding the proper way to write an object from an Intent Service scenario is:

```
Realm realm = getNewRealmInstance();
try {
  realm.beginTransaction();
  Record newRecord = new Record().setField1(x).setField2(y);
  realm.copyToRealm(newRecord);
  realm.commitTransaction();
} catch (Throwable error) {
  realm.cancelTransaction();
} finally {
  realm.close();
}
```

?

In addition I am getting the following log messages (with no exceptions thrown)

```
E/REALM_JNI: jni: ThrowingException 7, std::exception in /Users/zaki/fromgit/realm/realm-java/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_TableQuery.cpp line 1285, .
E/REALM_JNI: Exception has been throw: std::exception in /Users/zaki/fromgit/realm/realm-java/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_TableQuery.cpp line 1285
```

Answer (score 1):

> "Mixing asynchronous queries with local writes should be avoided. Realm will convert any async queries to synchronous in order to remain consistent. Use asynchronous writes instead."

You only get this warning if you execute synchronous writes on the UI thread. Surely you can ensure that you don't write on the UI thread?

---

This works for intent service :

```
 Realm realm = getNewRealmInstance();
 try {
       realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                Record newRecord = new Record().setField1(x).setField2(y);
                realm.insert(newRecord);
            } 
       });
 } finally {
       realm.close();
 }
```

Comment: Intent Services run in their own threads, NOT on the UI thread according to the Android documentation, also, this is the same as the code I asked about except it doesn't catch exceptions.

Comment: That's wonderful, but do you actually have this code snippet inside `onHandleIntent()`?